# IIS and Entity Framework connectionstring seem duplicated but cannot see where

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5

When I run my asp.net mvc2 web application using IIS7.5 and connecting up to SQL2008 I get the following messge:

"The entry 'XXXEntities' has already been added.\Projects\ProjectName\web.config line 32"

Now I think from what I previously read that IIS is reading it twice but can only find this string in the root web.config.

Can anyone give me an idea what I can do to get over this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<clear/>` tag like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="blah,blah,etc." />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use configuration editor inside IIs Manager,so open inetmgr.exe, go to the site or application where you are seeing the problem and double click the configuration editor icon, select the connextionStrings section. You will probably see the error popup, but now change the location drop Down until you are able to get the data. When you open the collection editor you will see the location where each entry was added.